What is the maximum sum of all skyscraper clues in a sudoku?
I stumbled upon a problem which seems hard to answer. It involves the sudoku game and a commonly used custom constraint rule called "skyscrapers".
The rules of a normal 9x9 sudoku puzzle are: Each row and column and 3x3 box contain the digits 1-9 once each.
The rules for skyscraper clues are: Clues outside the grid indicate how many numbers can be "seen" when looking into the grid along the row or column. A number is visible only when it is larger than all numbers that appear before it along the line of sight.
Now, imagine a grid that is surrounded by skyscraper clues, i.e. each row and column is affected by a skyscraper clue from the top and bottom or left and right.
What is the maximum possible sum of all skyscraper clues with a valid solution?
Here is a grid I discovered with a sum of 122 - the biggest I could find yet:


Such questions are often also asked on the CTC Community Discord (Theory and Programming thread, for example) - if you know it. [CTC=Cracking the Cryptic]

I confirm that your example grid yields a sum of $122$.  By considering the placements of the nines, you can deduce an upper bound of $4(1+2+\dots+9)=180$.  Via integer linear programming, I found that the maximum is at least $131$:
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 7 & 6\\
3 & 4 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 2 & 1 & 5\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 9\\
7 & 9 & 6 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 5 & 2 & 1\\
8 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 9 & 7 & 6 & 4 & 3\\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 1 & 7 & 9 & 8\\
9 & 8 & 3 & 7 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 2\\
6 & 7 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 8 & 9 & 5 & 4\\
4 & 5 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 9 & 8 & 3 & 7\\
\end{matrix}

Here's 132, found using a SAT solver: 
I've also found 138 to be an upper bound, but I was unable to narrow it down further.
